# Initializing a variable and passing it as a parameter vs initializing in method body

Tags: c#, variables

In C#, does anyone know if doing this...

```
 public object Foo()
 {
    var command = new MyCommand(param1);
    return Myfunction(command);
 }
```

is less efficient (uses more memory) than doing this?

```
 public object Foo()
 {
    return Myfunction(new MyCommand(param1));
 }
```

Or is the difference only cosmetic? It seems like the first option would consume a little more memory until the variable falls out of scope. I realize any difference would be very small. Also, is there name for 2nd syntax? inline? something? Thanks!

Comment: A smart compiler will optimize both object and generate similar code.

Comment: The memory for the object has to be allocated in both cases. There should be no difference.

Comment: "Inline" would be appropriate, yes. There's likely no difference in the compiled code, and the object will live the same in both cases (until `Myfunction` finishes), so the "scope" is the same

Comment: Please copy-paste your sample code into [sharplab](https://sharplab.io/) and switch on `IL` on the right hand side panel to see the difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the compiler, it is exactly the same.  Both will get converted to the same IL code.

Two things to keep in mind.

First, how readable is your code?  With a single variable it looks fine, but what happens if you are passing in multiple variables or doing nested function calls like `return Myfunction(new MyCommand(MyOtherFunction(MyThirdFunction(param1))));`?  Technically, this is correct but it makes it much harder to read and understand.

Second, how easy it is to debug?  What happens if your `command` is `null`.  Do you need to check it and if yes, where?  Based on `param1`, you may not know the value of the command until further in your code so if something goes wrong, it may be much harder to find where.

```
 public object Foo()
 {
    var command = new MyCommand(param1); // what happens if param1 is invalid?
    
    if (command != null) // yes, this can be done on one line
    {
        return MyFunction(command);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Bad command"), ex);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference. The compiler will optimize the `command` variable away.